# Warning C6386: "Переполнение буфера при записи в..."

Tags: c, malloc

Функция считывает матрицу из файла в динамический массив, сразу же выводит её и отправляет в main, предварительно узнав размеры этой матрицы из другой функции (плюс разные проверки существования файла и прочее, но не суть). Сама программа и данная функция работают безупречно, но анализ кода в Visual Studio выдаёт вот такое вот предупреждение:

> Предупреждение    C6386.  Переполнение буфера при записи в "matrix": 
>   доступный для записи объем равен "strings*sizeof(int *)" байт,
>   однако записать можно только "16" байт.

Так вот, мне интересно почему он на это ругается и стоит ли обращать внимание?

*P.S. Анализом кода занялся совсем недавно, к примеру узнал про нулевой указатель и в функции уже это дело подправил.*

Сам код:

```
int **GetMatrixFile(const char filename[], const int strings, const int columns)
{
    FILE *file;
    int **matrix;

    fopen_s(&file, filename, "r");

    if (file != NULL)
    {
        printf("Матрица %c(%d x %d):\n",
            filename[0], strings, columns);

        matrix = (int**)malloc(strings * sizeof(int*));
        if (matrix != NULL)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < strings; ++i)
            {
                printf("|");

                matrix[i] = (int*)malloc(columns * sizeof(int));
                if (matrix[i] != NULL)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < columns; ++j)
                    {
                        fscanf_s(file, "%d", &matrix[i][j]);
                        printf("%3d ", matrix[i][j]);
                    }
                }
                else exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

                printf("|\n");
            }
        }
        else exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        fclose(file);
    }
    else exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    return matrix;
}
```

Comment: Приведите пример файла, чтобы люди могли "протестить" сами

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лично мой gcc ничего подозрительного не заметил (у вас "C++" компилятор, а не "C", скорее всего).

По-моему, ваш компилятор хочет гарантию, что вы не переполните массив.

Собсна, ваш ответ [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37205179/vs2015-c6386-buffer-overrun-while-writing-even-for-same-index-value).

> Visual C++ Code Analysis tool set may not always offer best warnings.

Там и варианты решения проблемы :

1. Игнорируетете (что лучше не делать)
2. Исключаете возникновение этого предупреждения, используя директиву препроцессора `#pragma`
3. Используете другую конструкцию для создания массива (посмотрИте там же).